# Cane with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just discovered the [Cane gem](https://github.com/square/cane) but it doesn't work with Rails, there is a way to make it work with Rails?

**Update**
I'm using rails 3.2.1 and It doesn't produce any error message

Comment: What version of rails are you using and what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error message?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2.1 and It doesn't produce any error message

Comment: I got to know of cane recently, and tried it out. On first attempt, I too thought cane wasn't working since there was no output. However, I then tried out some of the options mentioned in the help documentation ( output from `cane --help` ) and started to get some output about where my code was in violation of the specific rule. Eg: Try `cane --style-glob '**/**/*.rb' --style-measure 80` followed by `cane` to see all the lines in the code that exceed 80 characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm the author of this gem.

How do you mean "doesn't work"? It's possible you just write good code :) The default options aren't too strict. Can you please post the output of:

```
cane --style-glob '**/*.rb' --style-measure 1
```

This should error on every line in the project, to verify whether cane is "working". And also

```
find . app
```

When run from within your rails directory.

Comment: I also added `app` to the default globs for version 1.1.0 (just released).

Comment: Did this work? Anything preventing you from accepting the answer?